# Flash Builder / Eclipse is not starting

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, flash-builder

It is stuck on the Splash Screen (or the dock icon has the 3 or 4 vertical lines). It doesn't go past that and no error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some searching and found that deleting the /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap file from the workspace directory solved the problem.